# Compute $\int_{\gamma} x dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals, contour-integration

Let the perimeter of the square formed by the points $0$, $1$, $1 + i$, $i$ and $z = x + iy$. How can i compute $$\int_{\gamma} x dz$$.

Some help to compute this complex integral please.

Comment: You could use Stokes' theorem, if you like overkill ;)

Answer (score 1):

Split $\gamma$ into 4 segments which are easy to parametrize. Calculate the integral for each of these and sum the results.